# Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider on local machine

Tags: enterprise-library-5

I am receiving an error message "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider." with Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write

```
    public void Write(string message, string category)
    {
        Logger.Write(message, category);
    }
```

Source File: Logger.cs    Line: 42

Stack Trace:

```
[ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow) +1480973
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +88
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings.GetDefaultMapping(String dbProviderName) +64
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings.GetProviderMapping(String dbProviderName, DatabaseSettings databaseSettings) +43
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings.GetDatabaseData(ConnectionStringSettings connectionString, DatabaseSettings databaseSettings) +28
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.<get_Databases>d__0.MoveNext() +272
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +439
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.<DoGetRegistrations>d__10.MoveNext() +137
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +85
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings.GetRegistrations(IConfigurationSource configurationSource) +161
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.TypeLoadingLocator.<GetRegistrations>b__0(ITypeRegistrationsProvider p, IConfigurationSource cs) +8
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.TypeLoadingLocator.GetRegistrationsInternal(IConfigurationSource configurationSource, Func`3 registrationAccessor) +74
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.TypeLoadingLocator.GetRegistrations(IConfigurationSource configurationSource) +80
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.CompositeTypeRegistrationsProviderLocator.<GetRegistrations>b__0(ITypeRegistrationsProvider l, IConfigurationSource cs) +8
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.<>c__DisplayClass5.<GetRegistrationsInternal>b__4(ITypeRegistrationsProvider l) +16
   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() +234
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.Unity.UnityContainerConfigurator.RegisterAllCore(IConfigurationSource configurationSource, ITypeRegistrationsProvider rootProvider) +159
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ChangeTrackingContainerConfigurator.RegisterAll(IConfigurationSource configurationSource, ITypeRegistrationsProvider rootProvider) +23
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer(ITypeRegistrationsProvider locator, IContainerConfigurator configurator, IConfigurationSource configSource) +19
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer(IContainerConfigurator configurator, IConfigurationSource configSource) +117
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(IConfigurationSource configurationSource) +59
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.SetCurrentContainerIfNotSet() +80
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.get_Current() +5
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.get_Writer() +73
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(Object message, String category) +16
```

Any help will be appreciated.